# Is there a close event for the browser contextmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, contextmenu

I'm catching the `contextmenu` event using jQuery like this:

```
$(document.body).on("contextmenu", function(e){
    //do stuff here
});
```

So far, so good. Now I want to execute some code when it closes but I can't seem to find a correct solution for this.

Using something like the following would catch some of the cases, but not nearly all:

```
$(document.body).on("contextmenu click", function(e){});
```

It wouldn't be executed when:

- the browser loses focus
- an option in the contextmenu is chosen
- the user clicks anywhere in the browser that's not on the page

**note:** I'm not using a jQuery context menu, I'm just using it to catch the event.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to notice that a contextmenu option is chosen. Why do you need to recognice that anyway?

Comment: @Bergi Next to the normal contextmenu I'm displaying my own, I want it to close at the same time as well.

Comment: Maybe this is worth creating a feature request for in all relevant browsers, I personally would like if this event and the `contextmenu` event had something to know how it was triggered (mouse, touch, keypress, …).

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 You're right, didn't notice the tag description. I've changed it to dom-events.

Answer (score 10):

Following code may help you. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfetN/1/)

```
var isIntextMenuOpen ;
$(document).on("contextmenu", function(e){

    isIntextMenuOpen = true;
});
function hideContextmenu(e){
       if(isIntextMenuOpen ){
            console.log("contextmenu closed ");
       }

     isIntextMenuOpen = false;
}
$(window).blur(hideContextmenu);

$(document).click(hideContextmenu);
```

Comment: Fixes the unfocussing of the browser but the other two cases still stand.

Comment: I believe It solved first and last problems. only problem remain is clicking on options of context menu that will fail only clicking on option does not remove focus from window.

Comment: When i click for example on the current tab the context menu closes but the window does not get a blur event.

Comment: in chrome 42 you can right click and hit escape and hideContextMenu doesn't fire, but if you click it does.  neat +1.

Comment: On desktop Chrome 53, the `'mousemove'` events do not fire while a context menu is open, and fire immediately when one is closed, so adding `$(window).mousemove(hideContextMenu)` to the arsenal, should fire hideContextMenu in every case.

Comment: this doesn't work in chrome. The first click which triggers the context menu to close doesn't register a click event. The fiddle doesn't work, at least in chroime.

Comment: In Chrome the event is (possibly) fired before the context menu is shown, see: http://crbug.com/748480

Answer (score 2):

I needed to detect when a context menu closes and so I came up with a solution.

Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/kexp0nmd/1/

```js
var premenuelem;

var TempContextMenuCloseHandler = function(e) {
console.log('closed!');
//console.log(e);
 window.removeEventListener('keyup', TempContextMenuCloseHandler, true);
 window.removeEventListener('mousedown', TempContextMenuCloseHandler, true);
 window.removeEventListener('focus', TempContextMenuCloseHandler, true);

 var focuselem = document.getElementById('tempfocus');
 if (focuselem === document.activeElement)  premenuelem.focus();
 focuselem.style.display = 'none';
};

var TempContextMenuHandler = function(e) {
console.log('open!');
//console.log(e);
 premenuelem = document.activeElement;

 var focuselem = document.getElementById('tempfocus');
 focuselem.style.display = 'block';
 focuselem.focus();

 window.addEventListener('keyup', TempContextMenuCloseHandler, true);
 window.addEventListener('mousedown', TempContextMenuCloseHandler, true);
 window.addEventListener('focus', TempContextMenuCloseHandler, true);
};

window.addEventListener('contextmenu', TempContextMenuHandler, true);
```

```css
html, body { min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>

<div id="tempfocus" tabIndex="-1" style="left: 0; bottom: 0; height: 50px; width: 100%; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none; position: fixed; outline: none;"></div>
```

Tested and verified working as of May 2020 on Edge, Firefox 76, and Chrome 80 for both mouse and keyboard.  Mobile/touch support unknown.

The key aspect of this solution is using an element that has a `tabIndex` on it.  By showing and moving focus to that element (focus stealing) before the context menu appears causes Edge and Chrome to send a focus change event when the user later closes the context menu.  I made the background of the div gray so it could be seen - in production, make it a transparent background and style it up however you want.

The `keyup` handler catches the release of the Escape/Enter key for when the keyboard closes the context menu.  The `mousedown` handler catches mousedown events in Firefox only.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to know for certain what option a user selected or even if they did, in fact, select an option.  At the very least, it allows for consistent detection of context menu open/close across all major browsers.

The textarea in the example is just there to give something else to play with for focus handling.

While this solution involves temporary focus stealing, it is the cleanest, cross-browser solution until browser vendors and the W3C add an 'exitcontextmenu' event or some such to the DOM.

One minor bug I just ran into:  Showing the context menu and switching away to another application closes the context menu but does not fire the closed event right away.  However, upon switching back to the web browser, the event fires and the close handler runs.  Adding a 'blur' capture to the window might solve that but then I'd have to re-test everything and it might break something (e.g. fire blur on opening the context menu).  Not worth fixing for the extremely rare occasion this might happen AND the handler still fires - it's just visibly delayed.

Comment: I like the solution but it doesn't seem to work as expected on osx, I've tested on firefox & chrome. Cannot currently test on windows but I think there's a difference, on osx, after the contextmenu disappears for any reason, you need to click again (or use any other input) before the event is handled.

Comment: I've run into additional issues myself with the above solution too.  I was focused on getting keyboard and mouse *cancel* actions working that I only minimally tested actually selecting items in the context menu.  Some context menu items fire events while others do not!  The browser (or OS) is eating events and/or not generating focus events like it should - even consistently re-firing a 'focus' event on close of the context menu would be a huge plus.  Someone suggested using mousemove but Firefox (at least on Windows) continues to process browser events with the context menu open.