# How can I detect when the context menu has been hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I'm developing an extension for Google Chrome using JQuery and Javascript and I want to set a variable to "true" when the user open the context menu and set the variable to "false" when the context menu is hidden.

I can detect when it's open with the following code:

```
var contextMenuOpen;
$(document).on("contextmenu", function(e){
    contextMenuOpen = true;
});
```

But I don't know how can I detect if it is hidden.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: There's no event fired when the contextmenu is closed, and I don't think there's anything you could check to see if it's open either, so I'm thinking this can't be done ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a close event for the browser contextmenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801898/is-there-a-close-event-for-the-browser-contextmenu)

Answer (score -1):

in the context menu definition you can implement the hide event function

```
events: {
hide: function(opt){
//.. do what you need
}
}
```

or i everywhere you need you could check if context menu div has the "context-menu-active" class

```
if ("#myDiv").hasClass("context-menu-active")) {
$("#myDiv").contextMenu("hide");
}
```