# Javascript detecting when contextmenu is closed

Tags: javascript, canvas, contextmenu

I have two canvases that are stacked on top of each other

```
<div id="canvases" class="col-lg-11">
      <canvas id="canvas"  style="z-index: 1;"></canvas>
      <canvas id="canvas2" style="z-index: 3;"></canvas>
</div>
```

When a user tries to save the image, I want #canvas to be on top so it could be saved.

```
$("#canvases").on('mousedown', function (e) {
  if (e.which === 3){ //right click
    canvas.style.zIndex = "4";
    return;
  }
```

However, I need it to come back down when the context menu is closed.

Is there an event for when a context menu is closed, or a more efficient way of saving #canvas?

---

**note:** There was a similar question in 2012, but I don't think the question was answered fully.

[Is there a close event for the browser contextmenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801898/is-there-a-close-event-for-the-browser-contextmenu)

The answer indirectly detects whether the context menu is closed (by checking clicks), but it does not check when a menu option has been selected.

I guess it's because there wasn't a direct way to detect a context menu closing, but was wondering whether it might have come out since then.

Comment: afaik there is still no reliable way to detect if a context menu was closed at least there is no event for it.

Comment: @t.niese that's a pity... how do others approach this situation then? I guess I can check every menu option separately, but it doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: Added an update with the timeout code that also seems to work in FireFox, it uses the capturing phase of the event to change the `z-index`

Comment: There's now a reliable, cross-browser solution on the linked post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801898/is-there-a-close-event-for-the-browser-contextmenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik there is still no way to detect this, but there might be another way how you can solve your problem, without the need to know this.

You could use `pointer-event: none` on the element on top if this is an option, that way the top layer would be ignored for mouse event, but this might have another side effect for your code.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}

.ontop {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <div class="ontop">
  </div>
</div>
```

Another thing you can do but I'm not sure if it works cross browser is to change the `z-index` on the `mousedown` in the capturing phase and after some milliseconds reset it, that way the event was still for the element you moved up.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 3) {
    $('.ontop').css({
      zIndex: -1
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.ontop').css({
        zIndex: ''
      });
    }, 10);
  }
}, true);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}

.ontop {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <div class="ontop">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The first method works nicely. I initially thought that disabling pointer event on the top element would also prevent interaction with the bottom element since it's covered by the top element. But it seems that the top element simply gets skipped for pointer-events allowing the bottom element to be still selectable.

Comment: @haedaldal `pointer-events` will only have an effect on the element you apply it on and its descendants.